# How to use group by only for some columns in sql Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, group-by

The following query returns 550 records, which I am then grouping by some columns in the controller via linq. However, how can I achieve the "group by" logic in the SQL query itself? Additionally, post-grouping, I need to show only 150 results to the user.

**Current SQL query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  l.Id AS LoadId
  , l.LoadTrackingNumber AS LoadDisplayId
  , planningType.Text AS PlanningType
  , loadStatus.Id AS StatusId
  , loadWorkRequest.Id AS LoadRequestId
  , loadStatus.Text AS Status
  , routeIds.RouteIdentifier AS RouteName
  , planRequest.Id AS PlanId 
  , originPartyRole.Id AS OriginId
  , originParty.Id AS OriginPartyId
  , originParty.LegalName AS Origin
  , destinationPartyRole.Id AS DestinationId
  , destinationParty.Id AS DestinationPartyId
  , destinationParty.LegalName AS Destination
  , COALESCE(firstSegmentLocation.Window_Start, originLocation.Window_Start) AS StartDate
  , COALESCE(firstSegmentLocation.Window_Start, originLocation.Window_Start) AS BeginDate
  , destLocation.Window_Finish AS EndDate
    AS Number
    FROM Domain.Loads (NOLOCK) AS l
    INNER JOIN dbo.Lists (NOLOCK) AS loadStatus ON l.LoadStatusId = loadStatus.Id
    INNER JOIN Domain.Routes (NOLOCK) AS routeIds ON routeIds.Id = l.RouteId

    INNER JOIN Domain.BaseRequests (NOLOCK) AS loadWorkRequest ON loadWorkRequest.LoadId = l.Id 
    INNER JOIN Domain.BaseRequests (NOLOCK) AS planRequest ON planRequest.Id = loadWorkRequest.ParentWorkRequestId
    INNER JOIN Domain.Schedules AS planSchedule ON planSchedule.Id = planRequest.ScheduleId

    INNER JOIN Domain.Segments (NOLOCK) os on os.RouteId = routeIds.Id AND os.[Order] = 0
    INNER JOIN Domain.LocationDetails (NOLOCK) AS originLocation ON originLocation.Id = os.DestinationId
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityRoles (NOLOCK) AS originPartyRole ON originPartyRole.Id = originLocation.DockRoleId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Entities (NOLOCK) AS originParty ON originParty.Id = originPartyRole.PartyId

    INNER JOIN Domain.LocationDetails (NOLOCK)  AS destLocation ON destLocation.Id = routeIds.DestinationFacilityLocationId  
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityRoles (NOLOCK)  AS destinationPartyRole ON destinationPartyRole.Id = destLocation.DockRoleId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Entities (NOLOCK)  AS destinationParty ON destinationParty.Id = destinationPartyRole.PartyId

    INNER JOIN dbo.TransportationModes (NOLOCK) lictm on lictm.Id = l.LoadInstanceCarrierModeId
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityRoles  (NOLOCK) AS carrierPartyRole ON lictm.CarrierId = carrierPartyRole.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Entities  (NOLOCK) AS carrier ON carrierPartyRole.PartyId = carrier.Id 

    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityRoles  (NOLOCK) AS respPartyRole ON l.ResponsiblePartyId = respPartyRole.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Entities  (NOLOCK) AS respParty ON respPartyRole.PartyId = respParty.Id 
    INNER JOIN Domain.LoadOrders (NOLOCK) lo ON lo.LoadInstanceId = l.Id 
    INNER JOIN Domain.Orders  (NOLOCK) AS o ON lo.OrderInstanceId = o.Id

    INNER JOIN Domain.BaseRequests  (NOLOCK) AS loadRequest ON loadRequest.LoadId = l.Id 

    --Load Start Date
    LEFT JOIN Domain.Segments (NOLOCK) AS segment ON segment.RouteId = l.RouteId AND segment.[Order] = 0
    LEFT JOIN Domain.LocationDetails (NOLOCK) AS firstSegmentLocation ON firstSegmentLocation.Id = segment.DestinationId

    LEFT JOIN dbo.Lists (NOLOCK) AS planningType ON l.PlanningTypeId = planningType.Id

    LEFT JOIN dbo.EntityRoles (NOLOCK)  AS billToRole ON o.BillToId = billToRole.Id
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Entities  (NOLOCK) AS billTo ON billToRole.PartyId = billTo.Id                     

 WHERE o.CustomerId in (34236) AND originLocation.Window_Start >= '07/19/2015 00:00:00' AND originLocation.Window_Start < '07/25/2015 23:59:59' AND l.IsHistoricalLoad = 0
AND loadStatus.Id in (285, 286,289,611,290)
AND loadWorkRequest.ParentWorkRequestId IS NOT NULL
AND routeIds.RouteIdentifier IS NOT NULL
AND (planSchedule.EndDate IS NULL OR (planSchedule.EndDate is not null and CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), planSchedule.EndDate,101) as datetime) > CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),101) as datetime))) ORDER BY l.Id DESC
```

**linq:**

```
//Get custom grouped data
var loadRequest = (from lq in returnList
                        let loadDisplayId = lq.LoadDisplayId
                        let origin = lq.OriginId //get this  origin for route
                        let destination = lq.DestinationId // get this destination for route
                   group lq by new
                   {
                       RouteId = lq.RouteName,
                       PlanId = lq.PlanId,
                       Origin = lq.OriginId,
                       Destination = lq.DestinationId
                   }
                   into grp
                   select new
                   {
                       RouteId = grp.Key.RouteId,
                       PlanId = grp.Key.PlanId,
                       Origin = grp.Key.Origin,
                       Destination = grp.Key.Destination,
                       Loads = (from l in grp select l)
                   }).OrderBy(x => x.Origin).ToList();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here really? Could you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: Show us an example of what you are looking for.  If you have two different rows with Column1='A', but different values for Column2 and 3, what should be returned?

Comment: @vignesh: What you want to achieve? Can you share input and output your looking for? You will need to have some aggregate function as well to use group by

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by leaving other group by columns

Comment: We need to see your sample table

Comment: I am not sure what was wrong i was asked. Some have edited and add a (how can i fix this) word in my question.
actually from my real query i selected 15 columns(ex.ID, OriginName, DestinationName, OriginDisplayId, destinationDisplayId, planId,OriginId, DestinationId, RouteId ,etc) from different tables using inner join with difference scenario. It returned 450 records.
Now I want group a records only by selected 4 columns(ex. planId,OriginId, DestinationId, RouteId ). but i did not used any aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to Group By column 1 but include columns 2 and 3 in your Select. Using a Group By you cannot do this. However, you can do this using a T-SQL Windowing function using the OVER() operator. Since you don't say how you want to aggregate, I cannot provide an example. But look at T-SQL Windowing functions. This [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/) might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing you need to understand about `GROUP BY` is that you must assume that there are multiple values in every column outside of the `GROUP BY` list. In your case, you must assume that for each value of `Column1` there would be multiple values of `Column2` and `Column3`, all considered as a single group.

If you want your query to process any of these columns, you must specify what to do about these multiple values.

Here are some choices you have:

- **Pick the smallest or the largest value for a column in a group** - use `MIN(...)` or `MAX(...)` aggregator for that
- **Count non-`NULL` items in a group** - use `COUNT(...)`
- **Produce an average of non-`NULL` values in a group** - use `AVG(...)`

For example, if you would like to find the smallest `Column2` and an average of `Column3` for each value of `Column1`, your query would look like this:

```
select 
    Column1, MIN(Column2), AVG(Column3)
from 
    TableName 
group by 
    Column1
```